# rs232 PTZ cameras software program for control

Tags: usb, camera, rs232

Does anyone know of a program that would allow you to control multiple IR cameras via usb (computer jack) to rs232 (camera hardware)? We have a cameraswitcher, very low key, that I can press buttons and it willswitch the view of the camera from one to the next. currently I control the cameras by sellecting the cameras via a remote control for change of angles. Does anyone know anything that could give me some ability to do manual controls via my computer?.

Please Advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of hardware devices that can transmit IR which could control these..

here's just a few... google them

globalcache.com

adi ocelot with and IR addon

bitwise